# resource id #4 Why am I getting this?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty basic forum template I am working on for testing purposes

When I create a topic, and press submit, the proccess updates the database but doesn't output on the screen. Why is this? and Why am I getting a Resource id #4 when I echo the $result from this code below:

```
<?php

$host="server"; // Host name 
$username="usernamehere"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="forum"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="question"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
// OREDER BY id DESC is order result by descending

$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo $result;
?>
<html>
<body>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td>
<td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Start looping table row
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"><? echo $rows['topic']; ?></a><BR></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['view']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['reply']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
// Exit looping and close connection 
}
mysql_close();
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><a href="create_topic.php"><strong>Create New Topic</strong> </a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because that's what $result is, a resource.

Comment: Just remove echo $result

Comment: shouldn't the while loop take care of the resource #4 error? and if I just remove the echo $result..I'm still left with my data not being displayed in the table..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting  `resource id #4` because `$result` is an resource,you must extract the values contained in it by this way,

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$values = mysql_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($values);
```

More about [resource variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

**Update 2(From OP comments)**

You are printing values using field name,In that case you will have to change to

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Or you can directly use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php),which in your case will be

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo $rows['id'];
}
```

Comment: ok, my data shows in the var_dump but it won't show in the table in the above code. Why is this if the information is being passed?

Comment: have you enabled short tags on your server, replace <? with <?php and try

Comment: @noob123 my mistake, i should have seen that earlier, check my updated answer

Comment: I used the mysql_fetch_assoc in the code above but it doesnt work..I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: adding the command mysql_fetch_assoc($result) worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Problem is in your code:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo $result;
```

`$result` is resource type, since `mysql_query($sql)` returns resource
Stop echoing `$result`.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error

Hence you are seeing the Resource#4

. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm simply trying to output the data in the database into the table in the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$host="server";
$username="usernamehere"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="forum";
$tbl_name="question"; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
// OREDER BY id DESC is order result by descending

$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo $result; //remove it
?>
<html>
<body>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td>
<td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Start looping table row
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo"<tr>
<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$rows['id']</td>
<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF><a href='view_topic.php?id=$rows['id']'>$rows['topic']</a><BR></td>
<td align=center bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$rows['view']</td>
<td align=center bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$rows['reply']</td>
<td align=center bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$rows['datetime'];</td>
</tr>";


// Exit looping and close connection 
}
mysql_close();
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><a href="create_topic.php"><strong>Create New Topic</strong> </a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**just check above code i think your problem should be done**

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to use mysql_fetch_array(). If you want, try something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC"; //that's your query
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$iteration=0;
echo "<table>";

while($iteration < $rows){
    $cell_in_your_html_table = mysql_result($result , $iteration , 'column_name_from_database');
    echo "<tr><td>".$cell_in_your_html_table."</td></tr>";
      $iteration++;
}
echo "</table>"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use code block for your code snippet in answers. Please double check your answers (yours does clearly have a `$num` variable being null which make your code useless). Please use relevant and readable name for your variable (tada ? Is that the result of an magical trick ?). Please make sure you are actually replying the OP question.